# How to get dSYM file from App Store Connect?

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, app-store-connect, dsym

i want to download dSYM file from App store connect, i can see the download option for download dSYM in `Build Metadata`, but when click on that link `download dSYM` it opening new tab and closing it, its not downloading any file

Please help me to find missing dSYM file, i didn't create archive in my machine, some other person have created build by using codemagic

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Right Click on "Download dSYM"
2. Copy Link Address
3. Paste that link in new Tab and press Enter
4. Done you'll be able to download dSYM